# mongoexport multiple in condition errror showing in db showing error Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: i

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoexport

AM getting  below error in `mongoexport`, multiple conditions in connections need to export it's working fine in studio 3t but in `mongoexport` command line not coming in output please help

```
/u01/ba/mongo/mongoexport --host ui-west-prod-mongodb-ent1-vm-01.az.3pc.att.com:17345 --authenticationDatabase admin -u 'm425@ub5@ub.com' -p 'prd@23' --readPreference secondaryPreferred --db entaction --collection statuses  --ssl --sslCAFile /u01/a1_cert.pub --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --type=csv -f "_id, tyId,Uid,uan,taskName,InsertTimestamp,UpdateTimestamp,results,status" -q '{"taskName" : {"$in": ["RT_WAP", "LI_WAP", "TI_SWAP"]}, "results" :{"$in": ["TIMEOUT","SUCCEEDED","FAILURE", "INPROGRESS", "SUCCESS"]}, "firstInsertTimestamp" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2024-02-13T00:00:01.000+0000")}}'  -o /u01/ent1_session_stats.csv
2024-02-15T05:25:26.175+0000    connected to: mongodb://ui-west-prod-mongodb-ent1-vm-01.az.3pc.att.com:1734/
2024-02-15T05:25:26.319+0000    Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input. Position: 177. Character: I`
```

trying to complete `mongoexport`:-
AM getting  below error in `mongoexport`, multiple conditions in connections need to export it's working fine in studio 3t but in `mongoexport` command line not coming in output please help

`/u01/ent1_session_stats.csv`:

```
2024-02-15T05:25:26.175+0000    connected to: mongodb://ui-west-prod-mongodb-ent1-vm-01.az.3pc.att.com:1734/
2024-02-15T05:25:26.319+0000    Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input. Position: 177. Character: I
```

below is connecting now if i have to pass date in variable how can i do that, as hardcode date taking but date in variable not taking:-

```
/u01/ba/mongo/mongoexport --host ui-west-prod-mongodb-ent1-vm-01.az.3pc.att.com:17345 --authenticationDatabase admin -u 
'm425@ub5@ub.com' -p 'prd@23' --readPreference secondaryPreferred --db entaction --collection statuses  --ssl 
--sslCAFile /u01/a1_cert.pub --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --type=csv -f "_id, tyId,Uid,uan,taskName,InsertTimestamp,UpdateTimestamp,
results,status" -q '{"taskName" : {"$in": ["RT_WAP", "LI_WAP", "TI_SWAP"]}, "results" :{"$in": ["TIMEOUT","SUCCEEDED","FAILURE", 
"INPROGRESS", "SUCCESS"]},  "firstInsertTimestamp" :{"$gt" : {"$date": "2024-02-14T00:00:00.000Z"}}}'  -o /u01/ent1_session_stats.csv
```

Comment: Rather than `ISODate`, use [EJSON v2 `"$date"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#options "link to mongoexport options doc -->").

Comment: it helps it but  in output  result showing only for timestamp and taskname result not showing

Comment: Do you have a field named `" tyId"` (note the leading space)?  Insure string after `-f` is exact.

Comment: yes now it helps , space was constraint how can i pass the in this query as date.

Comment: See the example in [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#std-option-mongoexport.--query).

Comment: thi sis helpful, but i have to pass the date greater then last day, hardcode is working but if i have to pass in script : {"$gt" : {"$date": "2024-02-14T00:00:00.000Z"}}}'  how can i pass

Comment: Since your shell is interpreting the command, parameter expansion/evaluation depends on your shell.

Comment: it helps now issue resolved.